# Docker gitlab image installation - unknown shorthand flag: 'â' in -–hostname

Tags: docker, gitlab

After following the instructions at https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/ and https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-install-on-macos-with-docker/26374 on how to download and run the image on a Mac, I ran into the following error message in the terminal :

`unknown shorthand flag: 'â' in -–hostname`

Anyone has an idea how to solve this error ?

Full command : `sudo docker run --detach –hostname gitlab.localhost –publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 –name gitlab –restart always –volume /Users/Shared/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab –volume /Users/Shared/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab –volume /Users/Shared/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`

P.S. I tried rewriting the 'a' in the hostname flag but still get the same error.

Comment: sudo docker run --detach –hostname :  -hostname should be --hostname right ?

Comment: you're right, that's one of the problems ! the other one was that this character : '–' versus '-'. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing "–" with "--"

```
sudo docker run --detach --hostname gitlab.localhost --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume
```

Comment: This solves this first issue. Thanks ! Then I have a permission problem due to the usage of '/Users/Shared', but this can be changed afterwards.