# Github error on push: unknown shorthand flag: 't' in -t

Tags: git, github

Whenever I try to push to Github to any branch (even new ones), I get:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 't' in -t
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/***/***.git'
```

Same thing from CLI, Github Desktop, and Visual Studio Code. The thing is, the only flag `-t` in my whole repo is a docker one, `docker-compose exec -T laravel.test php artisan test`, which works just fine on another repository.

Where is this flag being set / where is the error coming from?

Comment: what are you actually doing and what commands are you executing ? 
have you looked an multiple similar google entries ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60441599/docker-gitlab-image-installation-unknown-shorthand-flag-%C3%A2-in-hostname

Comment: @Dmitry I am pushing to Github, using `git push`, Github Desktop app, or Visual Studio Code - neither work and all show this error.

I have of course pre-googled the question, but as your link indicates too, they all seem to be docker related. Even when I remove that line in my question, the same error appears. Additionally, the same line exists in another repo of mine and it pushes without a problem, so I don't think this is a Docker issue or that the line is actually the problem here.

Comment: do you have any hooks ?  it is probably something on the server side. it triggers some job that fails and as such fails the push as such.

Comment: @Dmitry Sure - I thought so too, but its a pre-commit hook, and the commit passes successfully. There isn't a hook on push per se.

Comment: pre-commit hook has already passed. so , the push is rejected by the server and message comes from the server.

Comment: when you say you push something to the new branch. does it mean you push the same code from the old branch ? try to create a branch , delete everything and commit-push.

Comment: By server you mean Github right? And that's why I don't get where the unknown shorthand flag is coming from, since there's no such flag being used on push. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237727/discussion-between-michal-and-dmitry).

Comment: @Dmitry: if it were on the server side, the message would be `remote: unknown shorthand flag: 't' in -t`. (Just an item for future debugging.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so was a weird issue with composer hooks and git. In the .git folder, I deleted the hooks folder and then ran composer update, which also re-added the hooks correctly this time.